# How to creating multiple Sitemaps in PHP in this code

Tags: php, web, sitemap

The following code generates URLs for a sitemap. After 50,000 urls, the following code will not make a new sitemap (i.e. sitemap2.xml or sitemap3.xml)

```
header('Content-type: application/xml; charset="ISO-8859-1"', true);
$dataAll1 = scandir('cache-data');
unset($dataAll1[0]);
unset($dataAll1[1]);
unset($dataAll1[2]);
$sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <urlset xmlns="'.PROTOCOL.'://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

$sitemap .= '<url>
                        <loc>' . SITE_HOST . '</loc>
                        <priority>1.0</priority>
                     </url>';

foreach($dataAll1 as $val){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('cache-data/'.$val),1);
    if($val=='index.php'){
        continue;
    }
    $sitemap .= '<url>
                   <loc>'.SITE_HOST . '/blog/' . $data['jk'].'jktk'.$data['tk'] . '-' . $service->slugify($data['title']).'</loc>
                        <priority>0.9</priority>
                        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
                     </url>';
}

$sitemap.='</urlset>';
echo $sitemap;
```

What correction is needed to the code above so that it creates a new sitemap after reaching 50,000 URLs?

Comment: You have to create sitemap dynamically. so that it will solve your issue. you can make a counter. when the counter reached 50k then you would create another sitemap file. you can push the content inside that file

Comment: how to apply it in the php code above? could you help?

Answer (score 0):

It may help to solve your problem. Please have a look below code:

```
define('PROTOCOL', 'url');
$sitemapStart = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <urlset xmlns="'.PROTOCOL.'://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

$sitemapEnd ='</urlset>';

$maxLength= 30;
$fileName = 'sitemap';$filenameInc = 0;
$inc = 0;
$sitemapList = '';
for ($i=1; $i <= 100; $i++) 
{     
    $sitemapList .= '
<url>
<loc>URL</loc>
<priority>0.9</priority>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>';
    # code...
    if ($maxLength == $inc || $i == 100)
    {
        $fileName = "sitemap";
        if ($filenameInc > 0)
        {
            $fileName .= $filenameInc;
        }
        $fileName .= ".php";
        $sitemap = $sitemapStart . $sitemapList .$sitemapEnd;
       // echo  $sitemap;
        if(!file_put_contents($fileName, $sitemap))
        {
            // overwriting the file failed (permission problem maybe), debug or log here
        }
        $inc = 0;
        $filenameInc++;
        $sitemapList = '';
    }
    else {
        $inc++;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate out the xml generation code into it's own function like so:

```
function createSiteMap($data) {
    $sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<urlset xmlns="'.PROTOCOL.'://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">\n';
    $sitemap .= '\t<url>\n\t\t<loc>' . SITE_HOST . '</loc>\n\t\t<priority>1.0</priority>\n\t</url>\n';
    foreach($data as $val) {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('cache-data/'.$val),1);
        if($val=='index.php') continue;
        $sitemap .= '\t<url>\n';
        $sitemap .= '\t\t<loc>'.SITE_HOST . '/blog/' . $data['jk'].'jktk'.$data['tk'] . '-' . $service->slugify($data['title']).'</loc>\n';
        $sitemap .= '\t\t<priority>0.9</priority>\n';
        $sitemap .= '\t\t<changefreq>daily</changefreq>\n';
        $sitemap .= '\t</url>\n';
    }
    $sitemap.='</urlset>\n';

    return $sitemap
}
```

Then you can iterate over your array and slice it up how you like:

```
$dataAll1 = scandir('cache-data');
unset($dataAll1[0]);
unset($dataAll1[1]);
unset($dataAll1[2]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $dataAll1; $i = $i + 50000) {
    $partial = array_slice($dataAll1, $i, 50000); // What if there isn't 50,000 elements left in the array?
    $result = createSiteMap($partial);
}
```